# RewriteRule apache

Tags: apache-2.2

```
<Location "/site">
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/site
</Location>


<Location "/site2">
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/site2
</Location>

<Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /home/svn
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Subversion Repository"
     AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
     <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
     </LimitExcept>
</Location>

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond  %{query_string}  !^/svn/.*
RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule (.*) ajp://localhost:8009/$1 [P]
```

my problem that the Rule is applied on /svn Location and gives always //svn please help

Comment: You may get better answers when you write a clearer title and describe in the question what you want to accomplish and what you're seeing instead. The question is unclear now.

Answer (score 1):

Your RewriteCond matches on `svn/` because you don't want to accidentally match `svnabc`, but then, of course, it won't match `svn` without trailing slash either. Maybe `/svn(/.*)?$` is closer to what you want, i.e. "start with /svn, and then maybe something else, but that'll have to start with a slash"?

Comment: Thank you for help but i cant understand you my problem that how i can escape applying RewriteRule on my /svn URL it always gives //svn can I apply deferent RewriteRule for every Location or i have to add a special RewriteCond